# jquery tag cloud not working

Tags: php, jquery, blogs

[Tag System I'm Using (Link)](http://primegap.net/2011/03/04/jqcloud-a-jquery-plugin-to-build-neat-word-clouds/)

Simply put the inline tag is never replaced by the cloud

I have my JS loading in from a folder (links confirmed)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jqquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jqcloud-1.0.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jquery/jqcloud.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

and then i use some PHP to generate the tag array

```
<script type="text/jscript">
var word_list = [
<?
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
if ($value == $average) { $weight = 2;} 
else if ($value > $average) { $weight = 3;} 
else if ($value < $average) { $weight = 1;}
if (strlen($key) > 1 ){
  echo "{text: \"".$key."\", weight:".$weight.", url: \"http://myurl.com/tags/".$key."\", title: \"".$value."\"}";
  $total -= 1;
  if ($total == 0) echo ",";
}
}
?>
];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wordcloud").jQCloud(word_list);
});
```

Yet all i have is an empty div in my tag section

http://jsfiddle.net/K28Mc/ Functioning example

Comment: Can you please link to a jsFiddle? makes looking at the problem much easier :) Also, you should probably put your php code with JSON into a seperate file and then use getJSON() to pull it down through ajax.

Comment: updated with a jsfiddle example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you never close your array:

```
var word_list = [ // <-Note this character..
<?
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
if ($value == $average) { $weight = 2;} 
else if ($value > $average) { $weight = 3;} 
else if ($value < $average) { $weight = 1;}
if (strlen($key) > 1 ){
  echo "{text: \"".$key."\", weight:".$weight.", url: \"http://myurl.com/tags/".$key."\", title: \"".$value."\"}";
  $total -= 1;
  if ($total == 0) echo ",";
}
}
?>
}; //<------- Right here, you fail to close the array.  This should be a ].  I have a feeling this is breaking everything else.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wordcloud").jQCloud(word_list);
});
```

Comment: @ert3 Do you have a live link?

Comment: @ert3 I don't see that script included anywhere on that page.

Comment: sorry was playing with something else its back up, basically the script messed with other pages on general include so i was making sure it was only on the one page

Comment: 99 deep via firefox inspection

Comment: @ert3 Your cloud is working.  The only problem is your div is too small.  Though, that's with the test data.  Please update the page with the data that is generated from your php script.

Comment: for some reason it renders in anything that isn't firefox for me (go figure) and I'll go ahead and load up some dummy data

Comment: ok dummy data is up and looking decent, I need to play with the CSS a bit but yeah looks like you solved it thanks

Comment: @ert3 Welcome; glade I could help.

Comment: @ert3 There is only one last thing I can suggest in regards to firefox; put the script in the head of the document, instead of the body where it currently is.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($result['keywords'] AS $k => $keyword ) 
{

 $font_size = rand(10, 25);
 $fonts = array("Helvetica", "Arial", "Courier", "Georgia", "Serif", "Comic Sans", "Tahoma",  "Roman", "Modern");
 shuffle($fonts);
$randomFont = array_shift($fonts);
echo ' <a href="" title="' . $keyword['name'] . '">' . '<span style="font-family:' . $randomFont . '; font-size:'.$font_size.'px;">' . $keyword['name'] . '&nbsp;</span></a>';
}
```